# catching a Timed Out response as an exception

Tags: php, exception

30% of the time, my response via a AJAX call is returning 504 Gateway Timeout.
But I can’t seem to ‘catch’ it as an exception.

```php
try
{
    $response = $client->chat()->create([
        'model' => $model,
        'messages' => [
            ['role' => 'user', 'content' => $prompt],
        ],
        'temperature' => $temperature,
        'max_tokens' => $max_tokens,
        'top_p' => $top_p,
        'frequency_penalty' => $frequency_penalty,
        'presence_penalty' => $presence_penalty
    ]);

    $answer = trim($response['choices'][0]['message']['content']);
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    $answer = "Timed Out, try again";
}
```

Comment: The app where this is deployed to, is a $12 a month droplet at DigitalOcean where traffic is currently at 0 since I'm the only one testing it.

Comment: the 504 Gateway Timeout is too broad, this maybe because the nginx conf, so the first place to go with is to identify the root cause, it is from your PHP or the bad nginx conf.